# How do you prove that samples are equally distributed even when taken without replacement?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, random-variable

I was reading Casellar and Berger's book and came across this well-known property. Although, in the book, the proof for any Xi is not provided. Does anyone know how to follow up on it? I'm curious, is this a proof by induction?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please explain exactly what is being assumed about the sampling procedure and clarify what you mean by the "proof for $N.$"  The highlighted text says you can replace "$X_2$" by "$X_i$" for any $N,$ but because $N$ is not specified, any valid proof will automatically be valid for all $N.$

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit it.